# Easily get the stacktrace

Tags: java, gwt

In a GWT project, I sometimes struggle to understand why/when a method is called. In order to figure it out, I used to throw a dummy exception in order to catch it and access its stacktrace :

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace;
try {
  throw new NullPointerException("Dummy");
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
  stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
}
```

It works but it is a bit tedious to write 6 lines just to get the stacktrace (+ the stacktrace is polluted by the dummy exception). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GWT.log("hi", new Exception("This is not a crash"));
```